# Create SQL Query in function or PROCEDURE

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create function inside MySQL to create several queries for example :

```
    DELIMITER |
    CREATE PROCEDURE queryBuilder(_tableName varchar(100))
    BEGIN
          SET @str_query = 'SET @countRows = 0;SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @countRows FROM';
          SET @str_query = CONCAT(@str_query,_tableName, '; SELECT @countRows');

         PREPARE stmt1 FROM @str_query;

         EXECUTE stmt1;

   END|
   DELIMITER;
```

but it doesn't work? how can i change to work? I know i can create IF statement but i want something with more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare that variable before you set it. (I also chose not to use a reserved word in MySQL, i.e. 'count')

Like this (truncated):

```
 BEGIN
      DECLARE rowCount INT;
      SET rowCount = 0;
      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO rowCount from _tableName;

      RETURN rowCount;
 ...
```

See examples like this: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-function/

Hope that helps

Comment: thank for answer but that is not i am looking, 
 
i can create varchar then try to executed, but when i trying add set @count in to string query MySQL give an errors

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you say that the function creation errors at this line?

     'SET @count = 0;'

Comment: i changed my function to PROCEDURE but return empty row?